# Как соединить поля и получить значения из таблицы

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть таблица cookies и meta:

В поле cookies имеется имя host_key ( из него получаю параметры )

В поле meta имеется имя key ( тоже нужно получить параметры )

```
string selectCmd = "SELECT host_key FROM cookies";
string joinCmd = "SELECT key FROM meta";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как соединить эти 2-а selectCmd и JoinCmd в один запрос и получить данные?

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
"SELECT host_key FROM cookies Inner Join key FROM meta";
```

но безуспешно.
UP.

Comment: можно так попробовать: select c.host_key, j.key from cookies as c left join meta as j on 'здесь пишется условие объедения таблиц'

Comment: Не понял толком как это сделать, он не объединяет :(

Comment: покажите свой запрос

Comment: @Yaroslav, что за с. перед host_key? и j. перед key ?

Comment: `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)`